# Distribution of double negation

Tags: logic

Can we use double negation and distribute it like this

$$(\neg \neg p \lor -q ) \equiv \neg(\neg p \lor q)$$

But De Morgan's law isn't like what I did above!

Comment: $ \neg $ `\neg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use double negation and distribute it like this
>
> $$(\neg \neg p \lor -q ) \equiv \neg(\neg p \lor q)$$

No, you can't. Here is why:

When $p$ and $q$ are true, then $\neg \neg p \lor q$ is true, but $\neg(\neg p \lor q)$ is false. So these are not equivalent.

Comment: You're right; I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I almost added that comment to my Post, as I figured several people would do just what you did :)

Comment: I *was* wondering why you hadn't pointed that out. It turns out that you just read the OP more carefully than I did. :)

Comment: I wasn't aware that we should evaluate () before the negation.Thanks!

Comment: @Sun292 Yes, it's just like other mathematical expressions. Glad I could help!